# Define User-Defined Functions in SQL SERVER using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have manually created functions in SQL SERVER and then invoking those using the Sequelize Library in Node.js.

**Example:**

```
let query = "select * from getSomeData(:StartDate,:EndDate)";
let SeqOptions = {
           replacements: {
                           StartDate : '2015-05-03',
                           EndDate : '2015-05-05',
                        },
                            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
                }; 
 let result = await sequelize.query(query , SeqOptions );
```

But I have defined the `getSomeData` Function manually in the SQL.  Is not there a way to declare the function definition in Sequelize?
So that I do not have to run scripts in DB, whenever I restart my server and reset my DB?

Comment: Can you show `getSomeData` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it works for me:

```c
const procedureDropIfExists = `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getSomeData;`

sequelize.query(procedureDropIfExists, {
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.raw
});

const procedureQuery = `CREATE FUNCTION getSomeData(arg1 INT, arg2 INT) RETURNS int(11)`
    + '\tBEGIN'
    + `\tDECLARE hold_result INT;`
    + `\tselect dummycolvalue INTO var_value from tableName whereClause;`
    + `\tRETURN hold_result;`
    + 'END;';

sequelize.query(procedureQuery, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.raw
});
```

let me know if it works for you.